# Can't Use Multiple Middleware in same Route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel ui i'm facing problem when i apply 2 middleware in same route.
I Have 2 Type of user,
1.User Means Admin
2.Client

When I Want to login as Admin than i cant access dashboard but if i remove 2nd middleware from route than i get access to dashboard.
and the same things happens when i want to login as client. I've to remove Admin Middleware and insert Client Middleware.

**Route**

```
Route::middleware('auth:client','auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
```

**Home Controller**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('auth:client');
}
```

**Middleware Kernel File**

```
 protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'user.auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\client::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

}

Comment: You would not need both middleware. auth:client already means that use auth with $role='client' parameter. So the auth middleware will run having client parameter.

Comment: Then you should consider using route middleware. Create a different middleware with name auth.client or auth.admin. This way you can select different tabel. If you are using auth:client this means passing a parameter to auth middleware

Comment: i've created middleware named user.auth

Comment: you can check it on middleware kernel file

Comment: if you have created user.auth then you should use middleware like this. `$this->middleware('user.auth');`

Comment: if you are using middleware auth:client .. Note the colon here. This means you are passing a parameter client to auth middleware

Comment: You will obviously be not able to use same middleware with different parameter. So, you should use user.auth not auth:client

Comment: user.auth isn't working

Comment: if that is not working then refactor your code. Please read the difference between using : and . in middleware name.

Comment: I Just Used Middleware like this
Route::group([ 'middleware'=> 'auth:web,client' ], function () {
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
});
And Boyah Problem Fixed.